# Microsoft Graph: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph API on my ASP.NET Core app

```
var currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

it works fine for my public email on @hotmail.com address, but does not work for our corporative email with our custom domain. I get an exception

> ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message:
> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Is it depends on some security issues, configured by system administrator?

note: Authentication using "Microsoft Authenticator" is enabled as part or corporate policy

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create a client with creds.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=CS) You can't just use any client.

```
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "your tenant id";

// Value from app registration
var clientId = "Your client id";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

// Callback function that receives the user prompt
// Prompt contains the generated device code that use must
// enter during the auth process in the browser
Func<DeviceCodeInfo, CancellationToken, Task> callback = (code, cancellation) => {
    Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
};

// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.devicecodecredential
var deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(
    callback, tenantId, clientId, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, scopes);
```

Make sure your app is registered in Azure and provide the correct scopes.

Comment: It's configured on Program.cs: `string[]? initialScopes = config.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(config.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(config.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`

Comment: That means inside of azure, your client is sent up to accept this connection. Make sure your app is registered correctly and you're allowed to connect from your computer.